# The Error I see when I try to assign more than 6 elements to a tag of type RefGUIDList

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have a query in MGD technology regarding a tagged value of Type “RefGUIDList”.

I am using MDG technology in which I am giving the tagged value of type “RefGUIDList”, which should refer to maximum number(multiplicity 0-n) of elements. But in MDG it is not able to refer more than 6 elements.

The error I see when I try to assign more than 6 elements to a tag of type RefGUIDList.
[image]

Please tell me is there any way to increase the count of the references or let me know is there any other tagged value for referring maximum number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could tweak you database schema for `t_objectproperties.value` so they can hold more chars. But this is absolutely on your own risk. Some people have done so with different char fields. But you should first try in a sandbox to find out if it works without side effects. And of course you won't get much support from Sparx if something fails.

Alternatively you could send in a feature request. Postal address: Santa Claus, North Pole.

Comment: Using this query it is showing synatx error if we try to update the column datatype size Repository.Execute("ALTER TABLE t_objectproperties modify COLUMN t_objectproperties.Value VARCHAR(6000)");

Comment: You will have to execute the query directly on the database, not through the EA API

Comment: I never tried ALTER via Execute. However, changing the DB structure is better done with EA offline and a native client in any case.

Comment: I had no issue running `Execute("ALTER TABLE t_objectproperties ALTER COLUMN [Value] TEXT(200)")` on an EAP file (Mickeysoft Access).